# Как сравнивать значение datetime из бд с текушей датой

Tags: delphi, firebird

В бд firebird 3.0 в поле data1 типа Timestamp хранятся данные. Надо сравнивать значение из поля data1 с текушей датой?

```
 if  (Form1.Query1data1.AsDateTime <>date()) then ...
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы же сами привели пример кода

Comment: должен быть:
 if Trunc(Query1.fieldbyname('timestampfield').AsDatetime) <> Dateof(Now) then... 
спасибо.

Comment: или:
if DateOf(Query1data1.FieldByName('FTIMESTAMP').AsDateTime) = Date() then